# Passing text as param in textinput react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput, onblur

```
           <TextInput
             ref={(ref) => (this.qty = ref)}
             style={DefaultStyles.SeedFundSummaryTextInput}
              keyboardType='numeric'
              disabled={this.props.navigation.state.params.edit == false}
              theme={{ colors: { text: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)' } }}
              // value={item.qty <= item.allowed_bags&&this.state.enable_pc_limit_check==1? 
                item.qty.toString() : ''}
              value={ item.qty}
              onBlur={ (text) => this.handleOnBlur(text) }
              maxLength={5}
              onChangeText={(text) => { /*item.qty = text;*/ this.handleBags(text, item)}} />

                async handleOnBlur(text){
                console.log(text,'onBlur')
                }
```

Here is my code, i want to get the text in Onblur function as i get in onchangetext. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The event is passed as param to `onBlur` callback, which you can get text from via `nativeEvent` prop:

```
<TextInput onBlur={e => console.log('text', e.nativeEvent.text)}/>
```

You can find more info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onblur)

Comment: I am getting undefined in console

Comment: can you please show the updated code, and log ```e.nativeEvent```?